# Test existence of xml attribute in as3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

What is the best method to test the existence of an attribute on an XML object in ActionScript 3 ?

http://martijnvanbeek.net/weblog/40/testing_the_existance_of_an_attribute_in_xml_with_as3.html is suggesting to test using

```
   if ( node.@test != node.@nonexistingattribute )
```

and I saw comments suggesting to use:

```
 if ( node.hasOwnProperty('@test')) { // attribute qtest exists }
```

But in both case, tests are case sensitive.

From the [XML Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charencoding) : "XML processors should match character encoding names in a case-insensitive way" so I presume attribute name should also be match using a case-insensitive comparison.

Thank you

Comment: Woa... Flash just doesn't stop surprising me with easter eggs...

Comment: While it's not probably a solution, but I would get xml as a string, lowercase it, import as xml again and use case-sensitive search safely.

Comment: @jayarjo: ...which would lowercase all the character data content in the XML as well - not a safe way to process XML for any other use than the case-insensitive search of an attribute name.

Comment: Right... in my case I do not have any content in it, only structure, amazingly it just didn't come to me. But usually XML is all about content, so right...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please re-read your quote from the XML specs carefully:

> XML processors should match character
>   encoding names in a case-insensitive
>   way

This is in chapter 4.3.3 of the specs describing [character encoding declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charencoding), and it refers **only** to the names present in the `encoding` value of the `<?xml>` processing instruction, such as `"UTF-8"` or `"utf-8"`.  I see absolutely no reason for this to apply to attribute names and/or element names anywhere else in the document.

In fact, there is no mention of this in section 2.3 of the specs, [Common Syntactic Constructs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn), where names and name tokens are specified.  There are a few restrictions on special characters and such, but there is *absolutely no restriction on upper and lower case letters*.

To make your comparison case-insensitive, you will have to do it in Flash:

```
for each ( var attr:XML in xml.@*) {
   if (attr.name().toString().toLowerCase() == test.toLowerCase()) // attribute present if true
}
```

or rather:

```
var found:Boolean = false;
for each ( var attr:XML in xml.@*) {
    if (attr.name().toString().toLowerCase() == test.toLowerCase()) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) // attribute present
else // attribute not present
```

Comment: You are right, nothing in the spec say it is case insensitive. Moreover, when I validate an xsd agaist a validator (plenty could be found when googled), they give error if an element name doesn't have the right case. Thank you for you answer and the precision. I have no more reason to code an xml case-insensitive parser and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using XML's [contains()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#contains%28%29) method or XMLList's [length()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html#length%28%29) method ?

e.g.

```
var xml:XML = <root><child id="0" /><child /></root>;

trace(xml.children().@id.length());//test if any children have the id attribute
trace(xml.child[1].@id.length());//test if the second node has the id attribute
trace(xml.contains(<nephew />));//test for inexistend node using contains()
trace(xml.children().nephew.length());//test for inexistend node using legth()
```

Comment: "trace(xml.children().@id.length());"  and "trace(xml.child[1].@id.length());"  are case sensitives while the two other suggested way only apply on node, not attribute

Comment: Node search would also be case sensitive.

Comment: Also, contains would only return true if xml matches an entire node including all of its attributes and child nodes